# Define the Plugin In VB.Class

Tags: vb.net, plugins, interface

I know this is probably a frequently asked question, but I've been spending all day trying to find a solution to this problem. Now, I am working on a project in which VB is partially used. And in a program that has been made by someone else, there is a VB class that I want to develop little a bit by implementing a plugin in it to support dynamically extendable application core.

My question is how to replace "M1065" and "M1064" by using the plugin that I created earlier?

**This is the vb class.**

```
Friend Function GetWinderTrouble(ByVal lr As String) As Integer
        '左側
        If lr = Constant.YARN_WINDER_L Then
            Return Me.GetDeviceValue("M1065") 
            '右側
        Else
            Return Me.GetDeviceValue("M1064") 
        End If
 End Function
```

And this is the Plugin that I already created earlier

```
Imports IPLCComm

Public Class PlugIn
    Implements IPLCComm.IPlugIn

Friend Const YARN_WINDER_L As String = "L"

Friend Const GET_WINDERTROUBLE_L As String = "M1065"
Friend Const GET_WINDERTROUBLE_R As String = "M1064"

Public Function GetWinderTrouble(lr As String) As Integer Implements IPlugIn.GetWinderTrouble
    If lr = YARN_WINDER_L Then
        'Left side
        Return Me.GetDeviceValue(GET_WINDERTROUBLE_L)
    Else
        'Right side
        Return Me.GetDeviceValue(GET_WINDERTROUBLE_R)
    End If
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: To me at least your question is really that clear, maybe I'm missing somthing obvious.  The first instance of the GetWinderTrouble() what is that a part of?  Is that another class that also implements IPLCComm.IPlugIn?  What exactly are you trying to do?  Call PlugIn.GetWinderTrouble() or the other definition (wherever that comes from) using some overrides/shadows mechanic?  As it stands, looking at the code you've already in effect answered your own question

Comment: @Hursey : Thank you for your response in advance. GetWinderTrouble() is a part of interface plugin that I created earlier. I create interface plugin it called IPLCComm.IPlugIn and implemented to the plugin it called YWSPluginNS. And now I want to change GetWinderTrouble() value in the vb.class that I mentioned in above by using plugin that I created earlier.

Comment: I think the piece that you're missing is something commonly called Dependency Injection where you provide (something) with an instance of `IPLCComm.IPlugIn` (instead of whatever the original VB class is) and that (something) calls `GetWinderTrouble` on the instance instead of on the original class.

Comment: @Craig : Thank you for your advice in advance, but the thing that I need is just how do I change Return value of Me.GetDeviceValue("M1065") in vb.class by using plugins that I created earlier. Is that possible ?